# If there is no specific category it should print only “no category found”

Tags: java

```
public static String getLeastPriceToy(Toy one, Toy two, Toy three, Toy four,
        String category) {
    Toy ansToy = one;
    if(!one.getCategory().equals(category)&& !two.getCategory().equals(category)&&
        !three.getCategory().equals(category)&&!four.getCategory().equals(category)){
        System.out.println("no category found");
    }
    else{
    if(two.getCategory().equals(category) && (two.getPrice()*two.getDiscount())<(ansToy.getPrice()*ansToy.getDiscount())){
        ansToy =two;
    }
    if(three.getCategory().equals(category) && (three.getPrice()*three.getDiscount())<(ansToy.getPrice()*ansToy.getDiscount())){
        ansToy =three;

    }
    if(four.getCategory().equals(category) && (four.getPrice()*four.getDiscount())<(ansToy.getPrice()*ansToy.getDiscount())){
        ansToy =four;
    }
    }   
return ansToy.getName();
```

This should return only "no category found" but the Banana which is the first string is returned. How can I eliminate this:

[image]

Comment: `Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.` Going based off of screenshots is difficult for all of us and often leaves out crucial information. You should update your post to include the code and clearly state the question you have.

Comment: Include your `main()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're printing the result of `getLeastPriceToy()`, just replace

```
System.out.println("no category found");
```

with

```
return "no category found";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `System.out.println("no category found");` with `return "no category found";` you should get the desired behavior.
Right now you print "Banana" since you **always** `return ansToy.getName();`

Answer (score 0):

There is no place in the code in which you are returning "No category found"

You have printed it.... system.out.println("No category found"

But you actually need to add the line:

return("No category found");

that being said, it might be more useful to return something like null instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer has already been given here: Replace `System.out.println("no category found");` with `return "no category found";`

Additionally, this code has multiple problems, which could be mitigated with a redesign:

- To call the method with only one, two or three parameters you'd need to create a "FakeToy" that always has a category which cannot exist (your method doesn't check for null, so replacing one of the parameters with null leads to a NullPointerException)
- There is no way for you to compare five toys.

This version handles your requirements and doesn't have this limitations:

```
public static String getLeastPriceToy(Set<Toy> toys, String category) {
  Toy result = null;
  for(Toy toy: toys) {
    if(result == null || (toy.getCategory().equals(category) && toy.getPrice() * toy.getDiscount() < result.getPrice() * result.getDiscount())) {
    result = toy;
  }

  if(result == null) {
    return "no category found";
  }

  return result.getName();
}
```

This will work with an arbitrary number of toys without any code modifications later and is shorter than your original version.

Answer (score 0):

In main method 
I checked whether the category matches or not
 if  matches call the method 
 else "no category found"

this logic helped me...!!!
Ty all for answersing my question.